How can I get Facebook to unsuspend my account they disabled by mistake?
How can I get help from Facebook support regarding unsuspending my account they  disabled by mistake?
I have tried logging in and it states that my account is disabled. I have searched for help, but the results are confusing and I'm going in circles.

Is the  option to  appeal your suspension presented to you when you log in?

If you believe Facebook made a mistake when they suspended your account for violating their Terms of Service, you may be offered the opportunity to appeal the suspension depending on the violation.
Per Facebook's help document excerpted below, if you are allowed to appeal the suspension, the option along with instructions will be presented to you when you log in.

source: Personal Account Disabled
How to know if your account has been disabled
If your Facebook account has been disabled, you'll see a message saying your account is
disabled when you try to log in. If you don't see a disabled message
when you try to log in, you might be having a different login problem.
Learn how to fix a log-in problem.
What to do if you think your account was disabled by mistake
Accounts that do not follow our Community Standards or Terms of
Service may be suspended. If your Facebook account has been suspended,
you'll be informed about it in an email and when you access your
account in an app or web browser. We will also let you know whether
you can appeal the suspension if you believe we made a mistake. After
logging in, follow the on-screen instructions to submit your appeal.
Keep in mind that in some cases we may not issue a warning before
disabling your account. We also can't restore accounts that were
disabled for severe violations. Learn more about how we define severe violations from the Facebook Community Standards.

